# stored procedure, handle possible null value

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I have a very simple stored procedure which currently works perfectly when both parameters are sent values from form inputs.

However, I need to figure out what to do for IN_NUMBER if the value is empty because that column in the destination table is set to be nullable. It seems like the procedure itself is simply failing because it's waiting for a value.

What should I change?

IN parameters:

```
IN_NAME 
IN_NUMBER
```

Routine:

```
P1 : BEGIN ATOMIC

INSERT INTO schema . postings
( name
, postNumber)
VALUES
( IN_NAME
, IN_NUMBER) ;

END P1
```

Comment: I'm not DB2 savvy, but can't you default the parameter to `NULL` in the procedure?

Comment: I believe that would work actually for db2

Comment: How are you calling the procedure?  What is the error that you get?  Do you _want_ to accept NULLs?

Comment: @IanBjorhovde I'm just getting a general 500 because it's expecting an integer and getting a null, but yes I do want to accept nulls because it's not always required

Comment: There is no such a db2 error as “general 500”. What db2 error do you get when you run, let’s say, a db2 statement like `call myproc(‘myname’, null)`?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein I was referring to the web error but the sql error is expecting integer but got null instead

Comment: @TomN. If you need help, you need to show some actual code for how you are calling the stored procedure, as well as the complete definition of the stored procedure (i.e. everything between `CREATE PROCEDURE` and `BEGIN`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
create table postings (name varchar(100), postNumber int) in userspace1@

create or replace procedure postings (
  in_name varchar(100)
, in_number int
)
P1 : BEGIN ATOMIC
INSERT INTO postings
( name
, postNumber)
VALUES
( IN_NAME
, IN_NUMBER) ;
END P1@

call postings('myname', null)@

select * from postings@

NAME   POSTNUMBER
----   ----------
myname <null>
```

There is no any problem here as you see.
What db2 error do you have exactly on a case similar to this?

Comment: So the problem is, when I call it I'm binding parameters like so: ```$stmt->bindParam(1,$campaignName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(2,$groupNumber, PDO::PARAM_INT);```
It gives sqlstate 22018: invalid character value for cast specification

Comment: Show your call statement text with parameter markers.

Comment: Ah I figured it out, it was sending the empty value as an empty string rather than an integer or null

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle `NULL` and replace it with some other value, use [`NVL(IN_NUMBER, 0)`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlt.doc/ids_sqt_151.htm) - you can exchange 0 for any other number of course (I'm assuming this is an integer).